# Double Hashing java

Tags: java, hash, hashmap, hashtable, double-hashing

```
public class HashTable <K, V> implements Table<K, V>{
int idx;
PairHolder table[];
public HashTable(int size){
    table=new PairHolder[size];
}
public void put(K key, V value) {
    int hVal = key.hashCode();  
    int hashVal = hashFunc1(hVal);
    int stepSize = hashFunc2(hVal);

    while(table[index]!=null&&table[index].getFirst() != null){

        index += temp;
        index %=table.length;
    }
    table[index].value=value;
}
public int hashFunc1(int key){
    int abs = Math.abs(key%table.length);
    return abs;
}

public int hashFunc2(int key){
    int abs = Math.abs(5-key%5);
    return abs;
}
```

I am having a really hard time with double hashing.  Any help to complete this code to double hash would be great.

Comment: Java already has a Hashtable (lower case t), which implements Map.  I'd recommend changing your class name.  What is it you mean by "double hash"?

Answer (score 4):

What you're doing is not double hashing. For double hashing, you need two separate hash functions, not one hash function processed two ways. You're also not continuing the probe until you find an empty slot; you just assume the second spot will be empty if the first one is occupied. You're not handling the `table[col] == null` case, or the `hashFunc2(key) == 0` case, or the case where `col` is past the end of the table. See [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double_hashing) for more specific details on what you're supposed to be doing.

If you want to perform double hashing, you will need two hash functions. Java only provides one, so perhaps define a `Hasher<K>` interface with a `hash(K key)` method and take a Hasher in the hash table's constructor. Then your code might look something like

```
hash1 = reduce(key.hash());
hash2 = convertToStep(hasher.hash(key));
while (table[hash1] is occupied by a different key) {
    hash1 += hash2;
    hash1 %= table.length;
}
table[hash1] = key-value pair;
```

The function to `reduce` a hash to an index into the table can be pretty simple, but `convertToStep` may be more subtle.

To find another hash function to use, Google `string hash` and look at the options that come up. Many will be rather complex, but there should be some within the range of what you can handle. You'll want to avoid [the hash code Java already uses](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#hashCode%28%29); you want two hash functions, not one with two names.

To handle nulls properly, it's probably best to fill your `table` with `PairHolder`s when you create it. You can fill in keys and values when you insert items.

To ensure that your step size is always guaranteed to find an empty slot, you'll want to make sure `convertToStep` always returns a result where the GCD of the step and the table length is 1. That may be as simple as always returning an odd number and using power of 2 table sizes.

Comment: I have done a ton of research and I am still really confused.  Could you give me an example of what it would look like for my code?

Comment: @user3277779: Answer expanded.

Comment: so I would change my two hash methods to what you have there?

Comment: @user3277779: No. Most of the important things weren't fixed at all.

Comment: Ok I realize that. what about now?

Comment: @user3277779: Closer, but you still only have one hash function, you're still not properly handling null entries, and your step size isn't guaranteed to find an empty slot.

Comment: Ok so what would be the best way for me to do those?  Just if you were wondering, this is not a homework assignment.  It was last week and I got a really bad grade on it, so I am trying to learn from my mistakes.

Comment: @user3277779: Answer expanded.

Comment: I understand the english but when I try to put that into code I get extremely confused.  Is there anyway you could give a code example that so that I can compare the english to the code.

Comment: @user3277779: Which part are you confused about? If I give code samples for all the parts, I'll essentially be writing your hash table for you. This conversation is already getting past the "ask question, get answer" format StackOverflow was designed for.

Comment: Well my code kinda looks like the example code you gave, so I don't understand why it is so wrong

Answer (score -1):

```
    This is not Double Hasjinh .Go to This following link You learn Dounle Hashing.
```

http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Collections-Data-Structure/Hashtablewithdoublehashing.htm
bestlink to Undestand you

https://courses.cs.washington.edu/courses/cse326/00wi/handouts/lecture16/sld025.htm

Comment: I have done a ton of research and I am still really confused. Could you give me an example of what it would look like for my code?