# Trying to double hash

Tags: java, hashmap, hashtable, double-hashing

```
public class HashTable <K, V> implements Table<K, V>{
    PairHolder table[];
    int idx;
    public HashTable(int size){
        table=new PairHolder[size];
    }   
    public void put(K key, V value) {
        int hVal = key.hashCode();  
        int index = hashFunc1(hVal);
        int temp = hashFunc2(hVal);
        int col = index +=temp;

        while(table[index]!=null){
            index += temp;
            index %=table.length;
        }
        table[index].value=value;

    }
}
public int hashFunc1(int key){
    int abs = Math.abs(key%table.length);
    return abs;
}

public int hashFunc2(int key){
    int abs = Math.abs(5-key%5);
    return abs;
}
```

I am trying to double hash and I am confused on how to do it.  I think I am on the right track but this is giving a `NullPointerException` on `table[index].value=value;`.

Any help would be great.

Comment: What is the value of `table[0]`?

Answer (score 0):

Just think about this snipped for a minute:

```
while(table[index]!=null){
    index += temp;
    index %=table.length;
}
table[index].value=value;
```

That loops on infinitely until `table[index]` *is* null then proceeds on.  By definition `table[index]` must be null when you get to the last line, and will most certainly throw a NullPointerException when you attempt to dereference it!

Perhaps you intended something like this?

```
while(table[index]!=null){
    index += temp;
    index %=table.length;
}
table[index] = new PairHolder(key,value);
```

Not entirely clear how you intend to implement get after doing that...!  but it fixes your null pointer :)

If I "correct" your code to this, do you see why the poster in the other thread said you're not actually double hashing?

```
public void put(K key, V value) {
    int keyInt = key.hashCode();  
    int hash1 = hashFunc1(keyInt);
    int hash2 = hashFunc2(keyInt);

    int index = hash1 % table.lenght;
    int temp = hash2;
    //etc etc
}

public int hashFunc1(int key){
    int abs = Math.abs(key);
    return abs;
}

public int hashFunc2(int key){
    int abs = Math.abs(5-key%5);
    return abs;
}
```

Comment: what would be the best way to fix that?

Comment: You got a pretty good answer to this same question 4 hours ago... Don't know what else to add really.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21963881/double-hashing-java  ?

Comment: Maybe you could better explain it.  So this is not double hashing?

Comment: The point the person who answered in the other thread was making is that your hashFunc1 isn't a hash function.... all you do is %tablesize...  This table will 'work' pretty well in general since your key is the output of Object#hashCode which is already expected to be well distributed, but your h1 function is basically just `return key;` so it's not truly a double hash.... make sense?